# SELECT ORDER_ITEM_ID, PRODUCT_ID FROM DEMO_ORDER_ITEMS WHERE TOTAL_PROFIT >=, 300?

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help with this

I Put this but it is saying that there's a missing expression

```
SELECT ORDER_ITEM_ID, PRODUCT_ID
FROM DEMO_ORDER_ITEMS
WHERE TOTAL_PROFIT >= 300
```

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the text of the error message. That may help others to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You put it? Where?

---

I created a sample table (just to be able to run your code), and - everything is fine:

```
SQL> SELECT order_item_id,
  2         product_id
  3  FROM demo_order_items
  4  WHERE total_profit >= 300;

ORDER_ITEM_ID PRODUCT_ID
------------- ----------
            1        200
```

---

**However**: code in question is different from the one you put into the title. When I ran the *title* code, then yes - there's an expression missing:

```
SQL> SELECT order_item_id,
  2         product_id
  3  FROM demo_order_items
  4  WHERE total_profit >= , 300;
WHERE total_profit >= , 300
                      *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

See the asterisk, marking the spot? Remove the offending comma.

Comment: it still didn't run I don't know why but it keeps with the error. I saw over some pages that i have to put lenght and total profit on line 1 but I'm not sure.

Comment: Which tool do you use? Could you post a screenshot which shows it (code and error)? As of "put on line 1" - that doesn't matter, as far as I can tell.